# Azure Functions supporting async topic message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

I tried to make the azure function subscribe to a topic asynchronously.

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async static Task Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Executing!!");
    await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

When a message arrive, this fails with the message

I see the below in the Monitor section of the Azure function:
The BrokeredMessage with ContentType 'null' failed to deserialize to a string with the message: 'Expecting element 'string' from namespace...

I post a brokered message to the topic
using below code

```
TopicClient topicClient = GetTopicClient<T>(message);
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I copy-pasted your function definition and it works just fine. Do you also get this error when you hit Run button in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

**Mikhail** thanks for checking that out. I redid everything once again. Things worked fine. I am not sure what I messed up in my original setup.

thanks for pointing that out.